# Populate Java Array

Tags: java

I have an array with a user defined size of "a"

Once my user inputs all the data, I want to be able to execute a XOR operation on all the values the user has entered.

By adapting code;

```
int k=1;     
for (int k=0;k<A;k++){
k = ^piles[k];
```

*This code is in a loop statement.
I'm presuming its multiplying my value (once it runs the XOR operator) by 1 which is giving me the wrong value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do not use the same name for the loop counter and the outer variable.

Comment: Show us your code. What you posted here won't compile because of the duplicate local variable.

Comment: Yes, reusing the name is bad. The `for` loop is changing the value of `k` automatically as it loops, but you are also changing the value of `k` yourself, which makes array access.... interesting to say the least.

Comment: @ajp15243: you cannot say that reusing the name is bad. It's impossible, because it's a compiler error.

Comment: Multiplying any number by 1 will give you that number back. How could that give you invalid results and why would an XOR operation multiply by anything?

Comment: Oh derp, thanks @jlordo, didn't see that he actually redefined k in the `for` loop statement. Yes that would be a compiler error. Without the `int` in the loop, though, it would compile but still likely not be what is wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int result=0;     
for (int k=0;k<A;k++){
  result ^= piles[k];
}
```

Comment: That is what I've used, but once it runs the XOR operator, it multiplies it by 1, which gives the wrong answer. 

The XOR of 7,4,2,1 should be 0, but it gives me 1.

Comment: The code is slightly different(= ^ vs ^=). I'll check it again.

Comment: Why are you intializing result to 1? If you only want the XOR of the array elements it should be initialized to 0.

Comment: @user2023112, beaker found it. You must initialize result with zero.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought you could use 0, as it was multiplying the array elements, 0xE=0. But it works  now, thanks!

Comment: XOR is not multiplying. 0 * E = 0, but 0 ^ E = E.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer[] in = {1,2,4,7};
int result = 0;
for(int i:in) {
    result ^= i;
}
System.out.println(result); //prints 0
```

Comment: much nicer implementation